# What effect does importing only some functions of a module have

Tags: haskell, module

In Haskell you can import only some functions of a module like this:

```
import SomeModule(funFoo, funBar)
```

where `SomeModule` presumably defines more functions than just `funFoo` and `funBar`. Is this good practice? What rewards are there to doing this? Does it make the object code smaller or something?

Answer (score 7):

The primary advantage of limiting imports from a module is to avoid importing names that clash with another module (or the Prelude).  It does not make the object code smaller.

Comment: Another advantage I find to it is that it tells you a little about what the module does. If I see `import Control.Monad` I half-expect a lot of monad wizardry, but if I see `import Control.Monad (forM_)` I know all that really happens is some function looping over a list for side-effects.